# Typescript error JSX element type 'View' is not a constructor function for JSX elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

The program itself runs fine, but Typescript is underlining a lot of items in red in my return function for my components. Specifically anything coming out of my `react-native` import.

Anything like `View`, `Button`, and the like are throwing these "errors". I say errors in quotes because the app runs without any problems at all. Typescript within my IDE (VS Code) is the only thing complaining. It throws these errors if I choose (through the bottom right status bar selector) JavaScript React or TypeScript React.  Here is an example:

[image: Text Problem]

Here is the important bits of my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.3",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.7",
    "@types/react": "*",
    "@types/react-dom": "*",
    "@types/react-native": "*",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  },
```

And here is what a file looks like that is throwing these errors:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";

const SummaryScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const accountDetailsPage = () => {
        navigation.navigate("Account Details");
    };

    const contactDetailsPage = () => {
        navigation.navigate("Contact Details");
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>HERE IS A BUNCH OF TEXT</Text>
            <Button title="Account Details" onPress={accountDetailsPage} />
            <Button title="Contact Details" onPress={contactDetailsPage} />
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
    },
});

export default SummaryScreen;
```

I think it's important to note I do NOT get these errors on components created from `@react-navigation` such as `<Navigator>` and `<Stack.Screen ...`

Here is my tsconfig as well:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "jsx": "react-native",
        "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmit": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "strict": true
    }
}
```

Somewhat related, something in VS Code is complaining it can't find the module for `useState` but that also works fine when running, with no errors

Comment: Silly question, but have you installed all dependencies (including dev dependencies), or just prod dependencies?

Comment: I also note that you have `react-native-web` in both dependencies and devDependencies; any reason for that?

Comment: Not able to replicate with just what you've posted, unfortunately.

Comment: I did install everything fresh, and I found the answer. VS Code was using a very old version of Typescript for some reason, and was not using the Typescript version I set in my tsconfig. A simple fix, but hard to diagnose and pin down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was VS Code was using the wrong, and very old version of TypeScript. I'm not sure how it got set that way, or how it still had a version that was over a full release behind. Simple fix, but almost impossible to diagnose.  Here's where I fixed it:

[image]

As you can see, I had version 2.7.2 installed on VS Code itself and that WAS selected. I now have 3.9.7 used and all those errors vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Its really a pain to debug, 
 incase if you are using typescript in react-native. 
  in bottom of your vscode it should say `Typescript JSX` not typescript. 
 press on it and select Typescript Jsx.

chances are your vscode compilor may changed (stated above) or 
you made a silly mistake of naming your react component as example.ts  instead of example.tsx